# Not able to run Python app using flask run

Tags: python, flask

Below are my Python file name application.py. Here is a problem when I run this file in terminal with `python/application.py` it works fine and gives me the result. But when I try it with `flask run` it does not work and gives me the error, here is my error below.

```sh
Error :-
    
**AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'LemmaTokenizer'
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Aug/2020 23:31:05] "[35m[1mGET /predict?botinput=hello HTTP/1.1[0m" 500 -**
```

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, Response
import joblib
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk import word_tokenize 
import pandas as pd



app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/predict')
def predict():
    le=joblib.load('label_encode.tf')
    pipeline=joblib.load('chatbot_pipeline.mdl')
    
    bot_input=request.args['botinput']
    
    X_input_vect=pipeline["vect"].transform([bot_input]).toarray()
    y_input_pred=(pipeline["model"].predict(X_input_vect))
    y_input_pred_decoded=le.inverse_transform(y_input_pred)
    responsesdf=pd.read_pickle('responses.df')
    input_response=responsesdf[responsesdf["tag"]==y_input_pred_decoded[0]]["response"].values[0]
    
    
    #responses=flask.Markup(bot_reply=bot_input)
    resp=Response("{reply:'"+input_response+"'}",status=200, mimetype='application/json')
    return resp

class LemmaTokenizer:
    def __init__(self):
            self.wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
    def __call__(self, doc):
        return [self.wnl.lemmatize(t) for t in word_tokenize(doc)]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000)
```

Comment: you created class `LemmaTokenizer` but you don't use it in your code

Comment: Maybe you used it in different place as `__main__.LemmaTokenizer` but when you use `flask run` then it imports your `application.py` to other code and now it is `application.LemmaTokenizer` and it can't find `__main__.LemmaTokenizer` directly in other code.

Comment: @furas the LemmaTokenizer class used in this page chatbot_pipeline.mdl, loaded in this page here pipeline=joblib.load('chatbot_pipeline.mdl')
how to solve this issue ?? if this works fine for python/application and not working for flask run??

Comment: maybe you should put `LemmaTokenizer` in separated file and import it in when you created model (as `other_file.LemmaTokenizer`) and when you use it in flask (also as `other_file.LemmaTokenizer`) and maybe then it will be the same `other_file.LemmaTokenizer`

Comment: @furas LemmaTokenizer is used in another file that name is "chatbot_pipeline.mdl" how should i put differently please suggest ?? please let me know if you need to see the code

Comment: as for me you would have to change code which generates `chatbot_pipeline.mdl`